# Recursive To Iteratative - AVL Tree - isBalanced

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, avl-tree, iteration

I have to write an iterative algorithm to determine whether an AVL-Tree is balanced or not.

My first approach was to find a direct way, but after hours I gave up, so I wrote the algorithm recursive and tried to convert it.

here's the source code of the recursive-version (written in python)

```
def isBalanced(root):
    if root == None:
        return -1

    lh = isBalanced(root.left)
    rh = isBalanced(root.right)

    if lh == -2 or rh == -2:
        return -2

    if abs(lh - rh) > 1:
        return -2

    return max(lh, rh) + 1
```

My problem is now, that I'm not able to convert it, maybe one of you could give me a hint or solve my problem

thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to start from the leaves, because what the recursion does is go down to the leaves and propagate the heights of subtrees up to the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that recursive programs use call stacks. You can transform any recursive program to an iterative one by using a stack. In the following code, I use two.

```
def isBalanced(root):
    nodes = [root]
    results = []
    while nodes:
        node = nodes.pop()
        if node is None:
            results.append(-1)
        else if node == 0: # 0 is a flag we use for when we are ready to combine results
            lh = results.pop()
            rh = results.pop()
            if abs(lh - rh) > 1:
                return -2  # we could have continued with the stack; this is just a shortcut
            else:
                results.append(max(lh, rh) + 1)
        else:
            nodes.push(0)
            nodes.push(node.left)
            nodes.push(node.right)
    return results, # results will have only one value
```

Here, `stack` is a stack of nodes to check, and the results of those nodes.